# Cancel Paypal Recurring payments

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm currently integrating the paypal recurring payment process in my website.in my website users have the option to cancel his paypal recurring payment.i have the payer_id and payer_email of each users. is it possible to cancel the recurring payment with these details. if no ,how can i  cancel the recurring option if a perticular user click cancel recurring payment from my site.

thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can cancels all your paypal recurring profile with PROFILE_ID. and execute this code with your Recurring Payment Profile ID. Hope This Will help you.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
    'USER' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',  //Your API User
    'PWD' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',  //Your API Password
    'SIGNATURE' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',   //Your API Signature

    'VERSION' => '108',
    'METHOD' => 'ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus',
    'PROFILEID' => 'I-315LHdijsju',         //here add your profile id                      
    'ACTION'    => 'Cancel' //this can be selected in these default paypal variables (Suspend, Cancel, Reactivate)
)));

$response =    curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$nvp = array();

if (preg_match_all('/(?<name>[^\=]+)\=(?<value>[^&]+)&?/', $response, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches['name'] as $offset => $name) {
        $nvp[$name] = urldecode($matches['value'][$offset]);
    }
}

printf("<pre>%s</pre>",print_r($nvp, true));
```

Comment: This code is worked for me in first run. just change the params.

Answer (score -1):

You can suspend or cancel a profile by using the ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API.

Note [this reference](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted). This is specifically for express checkout but it will work for other paypal integrations.

This has also been answered here, for future reference: [Can you cancel a PayPal automatic payment via API? (Subscription created via Hosted button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809587/can-you-cancel-a-paypal-automatic-payment-via-api-subscription-created-via-hos)