# PayPal subscription cancellation without going to paypal site

Tags: asp.net, paypal

Can you please tell me how I can cancel PayPal a subscription without going to the PayPal site and remaining on my own site/interface?

Currently I have to go to PayPal site every time I want to cancel subscription.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you cancel a PayPal automatic payment via API? (Subscription created via Hosted button)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809587/can-you-cancel-a-paypal-automatic-payment-via-api-subscription-created-via-hos)

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on how to do this at PayPal's Developer Resources - [Handling Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/).

Comment: Thank you for answering. But it tells how recurring is done. Cancelling account always redirects me to PayPal. I want to keep my users on my site and cancelling from my site, not from PayPal.