# Best way to unsubscribe a customer from Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, web, subscriptions, unsubscribe

I have website with a subscription. What is the easiest or most common way to unsubscribe a customer. I use Php. The Paypal documentation I have seen indicates you go in manually and do it but there has to be an easier way?

Any help would be great,
Thanks.

Comment: It's not entirely clear on what you're trying to do... do you have a subscription on your site with a prompt when it's due for renewal or is there a recurring payment set up in PayPal? Do you need to just close the customer account on your system or also kill off that recurring payment?

Comment: Theres a recurring payment setup on PayPal. I just need to kill of the recurring payment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can suspend or cancel a profile by using the ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API. You can also reactivate a suspended profile. If the maximum number of failed payments has already been reached, however, you will need to increase the number of failed payments before reactivating the profile.

Accodring to PAYPAL you can take any of three actions utilizing the ManagerecurringPayments API. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/

Cancel - Only profiles in Active or Suspended state can be canceled.
Suspend - Only profiles in Active state can be suspended.-
Reactivate - Only profiles in a suspended state can be reactivated

Refer this link: [Can you cancel a PayPal automatic payment via API? (Subscription created via Hosted button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809587/can-you-cancel-a-paypal-automatic-payment-via-api-subscription-created-via-hos)